# Find files duplicates. Optimization

Tags: c#, algorithm, performance, optimization, filesystems

The algorithm is to get all files from the directory, group them up by their size, so we have <long(size), string[](file names)>, then compare files in "file names" buckets.
I'm not ok with current performance, it takes around 30-40 sec to calculate duplicates at the first try, and 3-4 sec after. (I guess my hard drive cashes these files)

I'm looking for the ways to optimize this code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;


static bool CompareFiles(string file1, string file2)
{
    if (file1 == file2) return true; 

    
    const int BYTES = 1024 * 10;
    
    using FileStream fs1 = File.Open(file1, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite); 
    using FileStream fs2 = File.Open(file2, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite); 
    
        byte[] buffer1= new byte[BYTES]; 
        byte[] buffer2= new byte[BYTES];
    

    while (true)
    {
        int len1 = fs1.Read(buffer1, 0, BYTES);
        int len2 = fs2.Read(buffer2, 0, BYTES);

        if (!((ReadOnlySpan<Byte>)buffer1).SequenceEqual((ReadOnlySpan<byte>)buffer2)) return false; // SequenceEqual is bad.
        if (len1 == 0 || len2 == 0) break;
    }

    return true;
    
}

static void CompareInDirectory(string startingDirectory)
{

    
    var dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(startingDirectory); 
    var files = dinfo.EnumerateFiles("",SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        .Select(finfo => new { finfo.FullName, finfo.Length })
        .GroupBy(file => file.Length)
        .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.Select(file => file.FullName));
    
    foreach (var entry in files)
    {
        var bucket = entry.Value.ToArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < bucket.Length; i++) {
            for (int k = i + 1; k < bucket.Length; k++) {
                if (CompareFiles(bucket[i],bucket[k])) {
                    Console.WriteLine(bucket[i] + " and " + bucket[k] + " are the same");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

 CompareInDirectory(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam");
```

I was suggested to use hashes, since "parallel" file accessing is not fast, so it is better to compute hashes and then group files by their value, but I don't really want to do it this way.

Comment: What's the rationale against using hashes? Is it the infinitesimal possibility that two different files will have the same hash?

Comment: If it's ok to only find duplicates that have been created via file copy (as opposed to having been created separately but containing the same data) you can optimise it by only comparing files that have the same `LastWriteTime`.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias One drawback of using hashes to compare files is that the entire file must be read to calculate the hash - but if two files differed in (say) the first byte, a byte-wise comparison would terminate after reading the first block.

Comment: @MatthewWatson in that case you could do a preliminary hashing of the first (let's say) 32KB of each file, and proceed with full hashing only for file pairs with identical file-size and preliminary hash.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I think that would make things slower. Comparing bytes without hashing is always going to be faster than hashing the bytes and then comparing the hash - no matter how many bytes you're hashing. This is exacerbated if the number of files is high and the number of duplicates is low. (If the proportion of duplicates is higher, then hashing *might* speed it up, but I think it unlikely that the number of dupes would justify it)

Comment: @Bookuha Another possibility to speed up the file reads is to use `File.Open(filename, new FileStreamOptions {Access = FileAccess.Read, Mode = FileMode.Open, Options = FileOptions.SequentialScan});` - i.e., specify `FileOptions.SequentialScan`. However, in my experience this doesn't seem to speed things up very much, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: @Matthew Watson the trick with hashing is that you do it only once for each file. As each file in a bucket is compared with each other, there is n(n - 1)/2 comparison per bucket, so each file is compared multiple times if n> 2. So this will in fact speed up things for files larger than their hashes.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias yes, this. And I just want to do it this way

Comment: @AloisChristen The thing about hashes is that if they match, you still have to read the entire file to make sure that the files are actually the same (unless you're happy to potentially decide that two files are the same when in fact they are not, albeit with only a one in 4 billion chance of a false positive for a 32-bit checksum). I've tried these kinds of optimisations in the past, and they've never helped because the number of duplicates (for my case) were too low to make it worthwhile. More dupes, or big duplicated files, and then maybe it would be. YMMV

Comment: Bookuha are you definitely against any solution that involves hashing, even if it's sophisticated enough that the probability of false positives is exactly zero? Also is it an option to load the contents of all files in memory (as `string`s or `byte[]`s), or their total size is beyond the capacity of the RAM?

Comment: @Bookuha a solution without hashes would be to store at what point files weren't the same, and play with those index to group files into further bucket of same files. That means, inside each bucket of file with same name, you have bucket of files with same content. Thus when checking a new file, you only check it against known versions of the file, and first at the index where differences where found in prior comparison.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Yes, we have some sort of competition in university, and I decided to use full check. I haven’t tried this yet, will check later. Thank you

Comment: Checking the file size before even opening the file would also speed things up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could optimize your current algorithm by taking advantage of the fact that the equality is a transitive property. So if you have found that the files A and B are identical, you don't have to check the remaining files with both A and B. If C is equal to A, it's also equal to B. Or if C is different from to A, it's also different from the B. So you can just compare the C with the A, and omit the comparison between C and B.

Similarly if you have found that the files A, B and C are identical, you can compare the next file D with A only, and omit the comparisons D-B and D-C.

The details of implementing this optimization can be tricky, so I'll leave it as an exercise for the reader.

This optimization can reduce greatly the total number of `CompareFiles` operations, in case that most files with equal size are also identical. If that's not the case, and it's common to have unique files with common lengths, then this optimization will not yield great benefits. In that case you could consider dividing the files in smaller buckets, by grouping them not only by their size but also by the hash of their content. The same optimization will most likely yield better results, because files with equal hashes are astronomically more likely to be identical¹.

¹ <sub>Unless the `startingDirectory` contains files coming from a research for [HashDoS attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_attack#Hash_flooding) or something.</sub>

---

**Update:** Here is an implementation of this idea. The `GetPairs` method below is a generic method that takes a list and a comparison function, and emits all the possible pairs along with the information if each pair consists of equal elements. This implementation makes the fewer comparisons possible, by omitting comparisons between elements that are known to be equal or different with previously compared elements.

```
static IEnumerable<(T First, T Second, bool AreEqual)> GetPairs<T>(
    IReadOnlyList<T> source,
    Func<T, T, bool> equalityComparison)
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(source);
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(equalityComparison);
    int[] state = new int[source.Count];
    Array.Fill(state, -1);
    for (int i = 0; i < source.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < source.Count; j++)
        {
            bool areEqual;
            if (state[i] == -1)
            {
                // The source[i] is different from all elements in the range [0..i].
                if (state[j] == -1)
                {
                    // The source[j] is different from all elements
                    // in the range [0..i].
                    // No precedent information available, we must compare.
                    areEqual = equalityComparison(source[i], source[j]);
                    if (areEqual) state[j] = i;
                }
                else
                {
                    // The source[j] is equal to an element in the range [0..i].
                    // The two elements can't be equal to each other.
                    areEqual = false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // The source[i] is equal to an element in the range [0..i].
                // The two elements can only be equal to each other, if they are
                // both equal to the same antecedent element.
                areEqual = state[i] == state[j];
            }
            yield return (source[i], source[j], areEqual);
        }
    }
}
```

A simple `int[]` with size equal to the list is enough for keeping track of previous comparisons.

The beneficial effect of the optimization depends on the percent of duplicates in the list. The highest the percent, the better. As an example, in a list with 100 elements of which only 50 are unique, the `GetPairs` emitted the expected number of 4,950 pairs doing only 1,767 comparisons (-64.3% discount). The `AreEqual` information of all 4,950 pairs was correct.

Usage example:

```
static void CompareInDirectory(string startingDirectory)
{
    DirectoryInfo dinfo = new(startingDirectory);
    string[][] buckets = dinfo.EnumerateFiles("", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        .Select(f => (f.FullName, f.Length))
        .GroupBy(e => e.Length)
        .OrderBy(g => g.Key)
        .Select(g => g.Select(file => file.FullName).ToArray())
        .ToArray();

    foreach (string[] bucket in buckets)
    {
        var pairs = GetPairs(bucket, CompareFiles);
        foreach (var (x, y, areEqual) in pairs)
        {
            if (areEqual) Console.WriteLine(x + " and " + y + " are the same");
        }
    }
}
```